# How to share the value of local property in class among different objects?

Tags: c#, .net

Ok so I am working with code that looks something like this,

```
class A
{
   public bool ProprertyDummy
   {
      get;
      set;
   }
}

class B
{
   void method()
   {
      A obj1 = new A();
      //Set and get obj1.ProprertyDummy
      //Share the PropertyDummy with method of class C
   }
}

class C
{
   void method()
   {
      A obj2 = new A();
      //Set and get obj2.ProprertyDummy
      //Share the PropertyDummy with method of class B
   }
}

class D
{
   void method()
   {
      A obj3 = new A();
      //Set and get obj3.ProprertyDummy
      //Should not affect the property PropertyDummy shared by methods of class B and C
   }
}
```

Now what I want to do is share property of class A i.e PropertyDummy among methods of class B and C but not D. The sequence in which the methods from different classes will execute is not defined and there might even be calls from one class method to other class method.

**Note :** I only want to share the property PropertyDummy and not the other members of class A among B and C.

Can anyone suggest some way to achieve what I am trying to do. Any help is appreciated.

For example now let us consider a class `Text` having a property `Visibility`. Now two different classes `TextNumbers` and `TextAlphabets` that contain a object of `Text`(not inherit) want to share the property so that change in 1 will be reflected in other. However there is no defined sequence for their use.
Now other class `TextSymbols` also have object of `Text` but does not share the property.

Comment: Pass the property as a parameter to the methods. Can you explain the use case in more details with some sample

Comment: This is more of a design-level problem. Perhaps class A, B and C have a different relationship than what is shown here.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya that can be a problem as methods form A and B are undefined and might have no relation among them,i.e maybe method from class B is not called at all or if it is completely unattached to working of method from class A.

Answer (score 1):

Make constructors for B,C,D classes and inject them A class object

```
public interface IA
{
    bool PropertyDummy { get; set; }
}

public class A : IA
{
    public bool ProprertyDummy { get; set; }
}

public class B {
    private IA _ia;
    public B(IA ia) { _ia = ia; }
    void method()
    {
        IA obj1 = _ia;
    }
}

public class C {
    private IA _ia;
    public C(IA ia) { _ia = ia; }
    void method()
    {
        IA obj1 = _ia;
    }
}

public class D {
    private IA _ia;
    public D(IA ia) { _ia = ia; }

    void method()
    {
        IA obj1 = _ia;
    }
}
```

and then in concrete use

```
var aObject1 = new A();
var aObject2 = new A();
var bObject = new B(aObject1);
var cObject = new C(aObject1);
var dObject = new D(aObject2);
```

Then to B and C instances inject the same A class object. Another A class object inject into to D class object. This way is probably only solution

Comment: Can you provide me with a good reference for above implementation.

Comment: I googled a bit and it seems this might work. If you can, can you provide me with a good article or post containing above implementation. Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e48607d8-01c3-432e-b5ad-d27024fd0460/sharing-variables-between-classes?forum=csharplanguage

Answer (score -2):

since ob1,obj2 and obj3 are 3 different instances of class A ,the property will not get affected to each other in any way ,i guess